# How to set values for multichannel matrix in Emgucv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I didn't find any explanations how to use a matrix with more than one channel im emgucv

```
var matrixa = new Matrix<float>(usablePoints.Count, 1, 2);
```

I tried with the Split() function but it didn't change the values of **matrixa**

```
var channels = matrixa.Split();
for (int i = 0; i < usablePoints.Count; ++i)
{
  channels[0][i, 0] = usablePoints[i].X;
  channels[1][i, 0] = usablePoints[i].Y;
}
```

What am I missing? How can i manipulate values of matrixa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `matrixa.Data`, this will be a `float[,]` with the first dimension corresponding to rows and the second being the columns and channels merged into one dimension.
If the number of channels is `N`, the current channel is `n` and the current column is `m`, the index `j` of the second dimension is

```
j = m*N + n
```

So, for your example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usablePoints.Count; ++i)
{
  matrixa.Data[i, 0] = usablePoints[i].X;
  matrixa.Data[i, 1] = usablePoints[i].Y;
}
```

should work.

A more complicated example: Say that we have 3 channels, 5 columns and want to set the value of the 2nd row, 4th column and 3rd channel to 1:

```
j = m*N + n = 3*3 + 2 = 11
=>
matrixa.Data[1, 11] = 1;
```